# Prevent Visual Studio 2013 to exit editing class tag when pressing SPACE

Tags: css, visual-studio, razor, intellisense, visual-studio-2013

The feature I like in VS2013 is the CSS Class IntelliSense in CSHTML files, however, their new feature to exit the tag when pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is quite annoying.

For example: I usually use Bootstrap with multiple classes, says:

```
<button class="btn_ <- My pointer is here
```

and I want to press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>and add `btn-default`, but instead, it jumps out:

```
<button class="btn" _ <- new pointer position
```

and it takes me more time to work with classes. Is there a way to turn this off?

*P.s: my current fastest way to overcome this is to press <kbd>ESC</kbd>before pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, trying out several combinations, using <kbd>Esc</kbd> before <kbd>Space</kbd> may be your quickest way. It also lets you "exit" when you're done adding all the classes you need,

e.g. `class="btn<ESC><SPACE>btn-secondary<ESC><SPACE>alert<ESC><SPACE>alert-info<SPACE>" <-- this quote is skipped at the last space and you can add other attirbutes`

Another option is to disable the auto-completion of attributes entirely. This can be done by going to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `HTML` > `Advanced`, then set `Insert attribute value quotes` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the ESC tip! But, this still happens to me with the `Insert attribute value quotes` turned off.

Comment: Same here.  I also use vim mode so I can't keep hitting esc.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Html > Advanced and tuirn off insert attribute value quotes. Yeh you have to put quotes in yourself but I would rather that then having to skip back every time

FYI the esc option didn't work for me

some one at microsoft needs a lesson in UX though for sure